# Delete statement - incorrect syntax near p1

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to solve this question from [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/delete-duplicate-emails/).

I wrote my query as below:

```sql
delete from person p1
where not exists
(
    select p2.email,min(p2.id)
    from person p2
    group by p2.email
    having min(p2.id)=p1.id
)
```

But I am getting the error:

> [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'p1'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: From the SQL Server [documentation of `DELETE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/delete-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) it seems that the table mentioned in the `FROM` clause cannot have an alias. It is listed only on the documentation of the expressions that can be used on the `JOIN` clause. *(I have never used SQL Server, I might be wrong.)*

Comment: `delete p1 from person p1` works fine. You are then in the `[ FROM ] table_alias` part of the grammar and have omitted the optional first `FROM`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the error message was very clear(error syntax), you don't have to make alias for table you want to delete.

```sql
delete from person
where not exists
(
    select p2.email,min(p2.id)
    from person p2
    group by p2.email
    having min(p2.id)=person.id
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an other way to do it :

```
delete from person
where id in (
  select max(id) as id
  from person
  group by email
  having count(1) > 1
);
```

You first need to get the duplicated email by a `group by` and `having count` > 1, from this list we get the `max(id)` (the last added email)
Then we remove it.

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/-MxDjTo9)